# Mysql table record limitations

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask two questions, The questions are below,

1. How many tables can we create into a mysql databse. and

2.How many records can we insert into a mysql table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:
[Table limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/database-count-limit.html) and here [Column/Row limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html)

Short answer: no practical limit on number of tables (limit to the operating system)
There is also no actual limit by MySQL on the number of records per table.